# Bug in RemoteApp for Server 2016?

Tags: windows-7, windows-server-2016, remoteapp

Needed:

- Fully updated win 7 client (v 6.3.9600)
- Remote apps installed on 2016 terminal server, also fully updated
- Multiple monitor's on the win 7 client
- Any monitor but the leftmost set as primary

When the above conditions are met and the client opens a remote app, the application opens fine, however if the user maximizes the window, then minimizes it to the taskbar, the next time they try to restore it, the window will appear (unresponsive) on the leftmost monitor.  It will however still respond to mouse events on the monitor where the application should have been restored to.  The only solution we've found is to close the offending app and reopen it.  This happens with all applications, explorer, calc, etc...
Has any one else experienced this or found a solution?  I contacted microsoft support months ago, and got nowhere.

[First opened Remote App](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wRPOf.jpg)

[After Minimizing, and restoring](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3FmE2.jpg)

Comment: After opening a support case with Microsoft, we have come to find out that this is an unsupported configuration.  According to them, the left / top most monitor MUST be primary, and all screens MUST have an equal resolution.  If those conditions are met the problem disappears.  This did not help us though, so we will be deploying server 2012 r2 instead.

Comment: The top left corner is not a requirement of Server2016. This requirement goes back to 2008R2.